# How to identify whether code is generated By Raphael or D3 library

Tags: svg

I am using D3 and Raphael both library for creating the graph.

Now, How could I know that which code is coming from Raphael and which is coming from D3?

Suppose I have customized all the code according to my need is there any way to know that using javaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Raphael sets `style="webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)"` on all the elements it creates, so you can do...

```
function isRaphael(element) {
  if (!element || !element.getAttribute("style")) return null;
  return element.getAttribute("style").indexOf("webkit-tap-highlight-color") != -1;
}
```